# Does quotient rule and negative exponent property sometimes lead to different answers?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

**So what should I do is taking the second derivative of:
$$[\frac{1}{1-\lambda t}]^a$$
with respect to t at t = 0.**

When I use the quotient rule to find the second derivative at t = 0.

$${\lambda a} * [\frac{1}{1-\lambda t}]^{a-1}$$

Is my first derivative and when I differentiate this expression with respect to t at t = 0. Using the quotient rule I find the answer as:

$$\lambda^2 a^2 - \lambda^2 a$$

Using the negative exponent property makes the expression:

$$ (1- \lambda t)^{-a} $$

and I find its derivative with respect to t at t = 0 as:

$$ \lambda a * (1-\lambda t)^{-a-1} $$

So now I see that it is pretty much different than the derivative of the same expression I have had by quotient rule. When I take its second derivative with respect to t at t = 0

I find the answer correctly as:

$$ \lambda^2 a^2 + \lambda^2 a $$

So where am I mistaken while applying the quotient rule?

Comment: It seems that the problem I have faced was trying to compute the derivation after the first derivative and then taking derivative of the computed expression. When I took derivative of the first derivative without computing, it lead me to the true answer which was $$\lambda^2  a^2 + \lambda^2 a$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the same answer by using the quotient rule as you do by using the negative exponent property. When you take the first derivative using the quotient rule, you should let $f(x)=1$ and let $g(x)=(1-\lambda t)^a$. That gives us $f'(x)=0$ and $g'(x)=-\lambda a(1-\lambda t)^{a-1}$. Then the function that you're differentiating is $f(x)/g(x)$, so its derivative is $\frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x))}{g^2(x)}$. Plugging in the functions we found earlier, we get $$\frac{\lambda a(1-\lambda t)^{a-1}}{(1-\lambda t)^{2a}}=\frac{\lambda a}{(1-\lambda t)^{a+1}}$$

which is equal to what you found using the negative exponent property. If you use the quotient rule on this again, you should get the same second derivative.

As a rule of thumb, if you have a fraction where the numerator is a constant, you should just use the negative exponent property, since the quotient rule will give you the same answer, but in an overly complicated form.

Comment: Yes after putting an effort of approximately 2 hours into this question I saw the mistake I made thank you very much sir. I will always use the negative exponent property in similar cases in the following days